# Manjaro Linux randomly fails to mount /boot/efi

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, efi, manjaro

A few months ago I started getting errors when trying to boot my Manjaro i3 Linux. It is completely random. Sometimes it boots from first time; sometimes it requires several restarts before it goes through.

I'm dual booting Windows 10 + Manjaro i3 Linux. The issue seems to happen almost every time when I restart from Windows and try to go to Manjaro. If the error appears, I cannot do any actions from the prompt. It's frozen, and I have to restart by pressing the power button. The prompt says that I could debug by checking `journalctl`, but once I manage to log in there's nothing there. I believe it would show the logs only if I managed to make the prompt work.

I read somewhere while googling that this can be potential issue with the order of the EFI partitions, but that seems unlikely.

My partitions in GParted:

[image]

Boot screen that freezes:

[image]

Comment: I'm gue4ssing you are not typing in the correct root password, since the screen png suggests you had tried and it is not frozen.

Comment: @Bib I did try tying both correct and incorrect password for root user, but it doesn't respond at all.